# C# ignore multiple strings between two characters

Tags: c#, string

I have the string:

```
"Hello, my name is <Enter name>, I'm <Enter age> years old and I like to play <Enter game>"
```

I would like to ignore all the text between the <> characters, and get the string:

```
"Hello, my name is , I'm years old and I like to play"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: any characters can be, besides '<' and '>'

Comment: then the duplicate should fit your needs. Just change the kind of brackets: `(` to `<` inside the pattern...

Comment: @MongZhu and there is no need to escape them because `<>` doesn't group

Comment: why is this question a duplicate of how to do a similar operation in regular expressions?  I suspect an answer to this question would be the same\similar, but not all answers.  though, *the best way* makea this question off-topic.. duping it to a particular way provides an impression that regex is the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegEx appraoch:

```
string source = "Hello, my name is <Enter name>, I'm <Enter age> years old and I like to play <Enter game>";
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Note: doesn't work with nested `<` or `>` characters

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ytohm